# seteuid in node.js

Tags: linux, node.js

How can I temporarily drop root privileges in Node.js?

I can see `process.setuid` in the standard library, but without `seteuid`, it cannot be temporary. Trying to get root privileges again fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think changing privileges in a Node.js program really makes sense because you don't know *when* the different IO requests are going to be handled. You might change privilege, submit the IO, change back, and at some point in the future the IO will be performed -- presumably under the privileges it runs with at the time.

I *could* imagine a mechanism to tie the euid, egid, and supplemental groups to specific IO requests, but it would probably be a drastic complication compared to their current design for not much benefit.

An approach you could take would spawn off new processes with [`Cluster`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#cluster), change permissions, and then exit the process once you're finished. You could also have it be long-lived and handle requests over an internal queue, but `fork(2)` is *fast*, and hopefully the Node.js shims over `fork(2)` aren't too expensive.

Comment: I see. Because `seteuid` was only possible with sync IO functions, which is frown upon, they didn't put it in.

I only want to create a file under a different uid. Creating a fork feels overkill. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [node-posix module](https://github.com/melor/node-posix#posixseteuiduid)'s `seteuid` method. For such a simple task as creating a single file, I can imagine that you use `writeFileSync` surrounded by calls to `seteuid`, as your original idea probably was.